# Get the latest month rows within a year?

Tags: aggregate-functions, abap, opensql

I want to get the latest data from a table in ABAP.

Here an example from the table `ckmlcr`:

| MANDT | KALNR | BDATJ | POPER | UNTPER | CURTP | PEINH | VPRSV | STPRS | PVPRS | WAERS | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 000100000000 | 2020 | 007 | 000 | 10 | 1 | S | 1.00 | 0.00 | JPY | ... |
| 100 | 000100000000 | 2020 | 007 | 000 | 30 | 1 | S | 1.00 | 0.00 | JPY | ... |
| 100 | 000100000000 | 2020 | 007 | 000 | 31 | 1 | S | 1.00 | 0.00 | JPY | ... |
| 100 | 000100000000 | 2020 | 008 | 000 | 10 | 1 | S | 1.00 | 0.00 | JPY | ... |
| 100 | 000100000000 | 2020 | 008 | 000 | 30 | 1 | S | 1.00 | 0.00 | JPY | ... |
| 100 | 000100000000 | 2020 | 008 | 000 | 31 | 1 | S | 1.00 | 0.00 | JPY | ... |
| 100 | 000199999999 | 2020 | 007 | 000 | 10 | 1 | S | 20.00 | 0.00 | EUR | ... |
| 100 | 000199999999 | 2020 | 007 | 000 | 30 | 1 | S | 25.00 | 0.00 | EUR | ... |
| 100 | 000199999999 | 2020 | 007 | 000 | 31 | 1 | S | 20.00 | 0.00 | EUR | ... |

I want to get the latest data for each `KALNR` so this would mean my output table should have following values:

| MANDT | KALNR | BDATJ | POPER | UNTPER | CURTP | PEINH | VPRSV | STPRS | PVPRS | WAERS | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 000100000000 | 2020 | 008 | 000 | 10 | 1 | S | 1.00 | 0.00 | JPY | ... |
| 100 | 000100000000 | 2020 | 008 | 000 | 30 | 1 | S | 1.00 | 0.00 | JPY | ... |
| 100 | 000100000000 | 2020 | 008 | 000 | 31 | 1 | S | 1.00 | 0.00 | JPY | ... |
| 100 | 000199999999 | 2020 | 007 | 000 | 10 | 1 | S | 20.00 | 0.00 | EUR | ... |
| 100 | 000199999999 | 2020 | 007 | 000 | 30 | 1 | S | 25.00 | 0.00 | EUR | ... |
| 100 | 000199999999 | 2020 | 007 | 000 | 31 | 1 | S | 20.00 | 0.00 | EUR | ... |

My program should have as selection the year

```
PARAMETERS: bdatj TYPE ckmlcr-bdatj DEFAULT sy-datum+0(4) OBLIGATORY.
```

and should uses the highest period (`POPER`) for each cost estimate number (`KALNR`).

What is the easiest way to achieve this? Due to a lot of data it would be nice to directly get the filtered data within the SQL select on the table.

This would be the SQL statement without any modifications to get the latest data.

```
  SELECT * FROM ckmlcr INTO TABLE @DATA(ckmlcr_single)
    WHERE kalnr = @<ckmlcr_line>-kalnr
    AND bdatj = @bdatj.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Learn how to use [subqueries](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_750_index_htm/7.50/en-US/abenwhere_logexp_subquery.htm)

```
SELECT kalnr, bdatj, poper, untper, curtp, peinh, vprsv, stprs, pvprs, waers    
  FROM ckmlcr AS cr
  INTO TABLE @DATA(ckmlcr_single)
  WHERE bdatj = @bdatj
  AND poper = ( SELECT MAX( poper ) from ckmlcr WHERE kalnr = cr~kalnr AND bdatj = cr~bdatj ).
```

P.S. Habituate yourself to put select fields explicitly [instead of asterisk](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_750_index_htm/7.50/en-US/abapselect_list.htm#!ABAP_ALTERNATIVE_1@1@), it will serve a good job in future.

Comment: Is the `AS lr` required here? It doesn't seem to me like you are actually using that alias.

Comment: @Philipp I've tested it and `AS lr` is not needed

Comment: Thanks @Sunscatcher your solution worked fine for me. Just one minor edit, I needed commas between the `kalnr, bdatj, ...`

Comment: `@Philipp I've tested it and AS lr is not needed` thx. corrected. Yep, good point for commas, with the new syntax with `@` you need commas instead of spaces

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is:

```
SELECT * FROM ckmlcr INTO TABLE @DATA(ckmlcr_single)
  WHERE kalnr = @<ckmlcr_line>-kalnr
  AND bdatj = @bdaj
  AND poper = ( SELECT MAX( poper ) from ckmlcr
  WHERE kalnr = @kalnr
  AND bdatj = 2022 ).
```

This solution only works for a single `kalnr` not as requested above for the whole table.

Thus means my program currently looking like this:

```
" get single kalnr
SELECT DISTINCT kalnr FROM ckmlcr INTO TABLE @DATA(data_ckmlcr)
    WHERE bdatj = @bdatj
    ORDER BY kalnr.

LOOP AT data_ckmlcr ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<ckmlcr_line>).

  " get the latest data from this kalnr
  SELECT * FROM ckmlcr INTO TABLE @DATA(ckmlcr_single)
    WHERE kalnr = @<ckmlcr_line>-kalnr
    AND bdatj = @bdatj
    AND poper = ( SELECT MAX( poper ) from ckmlcr
                    WHERE kalnr = @<ckmlcr_line>-kalnr
                    AND bdatj = @bdatj ).
[...]

ENDLOOP.
```

Due to a select in a loop that is not quite performant...